# Unity2d : How to increase the speed of instantiated prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a vertical endless running game so the spawns start from the top and travels to the bottom. I have these scrolling walls which increases speed gradually over time using `Time.deltaTime * accelerate`. I also have obstacles which are ***not*** spawned as the walls(s) child object but i want them to have the same speed. The obstacles moves downwards independently via script using `rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.down * moveSpeed;` where moveSpeed equals the walls speed but in Game View i can see that the spawned objects somehow are moving a bit slower than the walls so it looks like it's moving upwards instead of at the same time.

ScrollObjects :

```
float moveSpeed;
ScrollWalls scroll;
new Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    scroll = FindObjectOfType<ScrollWalls>();
}

void Update()
{
    moveSpeed = scroll.Intro_ScrollSpeed;
    //rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.down * moveSpeed;
    Vector2 bottle = new Vector2(0, (-1 * moveSpeed));
    rigidbody.velocity = bottle;
}
```

**UPDATE SCRIPT. UPDATE : I NOTICE THAT THE FIRST SPAWNED OBJECT DOES NOT HAVE THIS ISSUE, SEEMS LIKE IT HAPPENS AFTER THEY COLLIDE TO BE DESTROYED.**

Comment: If you are using `FindObjectOfType` anyway you could just make the `Intro_ScrollSpeed` a `static` and access it like `rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.down * ScrollWalls.Intro_ScrollSpeed;` Are all objects at equal distance to the camera? Otherwise your objects might have the same velocity but, you know, due to perspective they might appear slower

Comment: hey @derHugo yeah i changed that part of the script.

Answer (score 0):

In your instantiating class, have the same update and variables.
When you instantiate your object, simply call a function that will set its speed

```
Obstacle obj = Instantiate(Obstacle, transform);
obj.SetSpeed(moveSpeed);
```

Another solution : (or if you need to increase it over time) instead of that, simply make a static speed in you instantiating class and access it with

```
InstanciatingClass.MoveSpeed
```

So, you can use this too to set your walls speed, and it should be the same.